# Core Data – NSManagedObjects in instance variable update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Say that I perform a fetch of all entity `Employee` objects by doing: `NSArray *employees = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

Then I set an instance variable in my class by doing: `self.allEmployees = employees;`

Then later in my app I will do some modifying to my employee objects but not through accessing `self.allEmployees`. I'm modifying them from another class.

Will my `self.allEmployees` array be updated to the changes I've made from another class to the employee objects? Or will my `self.allEmployees` array be in the state that the employee objects were when I first performed the fetch? (I'm suspecting the later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you get back from the fetch request holds references to live managed objects. Unless you change a different fetchLimit or batchSize you get an array with as many fault objects as the query would return objects.

When you access a property of one of these fault objects CoreData retrieves the actual data for all the properties transparently and returns these to you.

A managed objects always has its own most recent value that was last called save on. So if you do a modification on the self.allEmployees you need to call save on the MOC and this will broadcast the changes to all other emoployee objects.

This is also the reason why KVO works on NSManagedObject properties, because they get notfified of all saved changes that affect them.

Comment: If my first fetch request returns 10 objects and I set my self.allEmployees. Then later in the app I have added 10 more employees then self.allEmployees would still only be 10 objects (not 20 as is the current total of all employees)?

Comment: That is correct, the NSArray does not magically grow to encompass all the new employees. It will only contain references to the ones returned from the first fetch request. You would have to re-fetch.

Comment: As well if I delete some employees, then I need to re-fetch? So all in all it's a pretty bad idea store dynamic data in a property?

Comment: You would have to refetch either way. Generally I would advise against long term storage of managed objects in arrays. Fetch them when you need them or go via the NSSet properties of NSManagedObjects which internally also just does a fetch. CoreData also does some caching anyway so you don't have to fear a big performance impact. In short: leave the managing of NSManagedObjects to CoreData. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you alter the objects you receive from the fetch, and don't copy them, then yes.
Those are all pointers. 
So you shouldn't need to do another fetch request.

If you change values of an employee, the pointer won't change. 
The only thing that changes is the instance variables, or properties.